# How to remove QMenu separators in Qt Designer?

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer, qmenu

I'm using Qt Designer with PyQt. I accidentally created about ten separators and cannot figure out how to delete them. They show up in the Object Inspector, but delete or right click has no useful effect. How can I delete them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can right-click the separator itself to remove it:

[image]